# Floating Nav Links to Right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get every link but the main 'Digestible` link to the right of the nav but keep them in order?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ut1poay3/

```
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><h4>Digestible <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></h4></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #ffcc00">Create a quiz</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Study</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Maxwell Gover
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There ya go....

Comment: What do you mean " get every link to the right of the nav", what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get "Create Quiz", Study, and "Maxwell Gover" links to float to the right but stay in order.

Comment: I have added an answer that I think is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/ut1poay3/6/)

Add a `<div>` that wraps "Create Quiz", "Study" and "Maxwell Gover" and float it right.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><h4>Digestible <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></h4></a>
      </li>
      <div class="right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #ffcc00">Create a quiz</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Study</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Maxwell Gover
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
```